# How to make a .sqfs file

Tags: squashfs

I've created an Ubuntu 13.10 Server 64-bit installation using a live CD. I want to backup the installation as a .sqfs file. I'm confused about how to do so. I looked at: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/mksquashfs.1.html and http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SquashFS-HOWTO/mksqoverview.html but there are no examples. I want to make an image that isn't compressed. Do I need to install anything in order to make a squashfs?

I'm thinking it's something like this to create the sqfs file:

```
sudo mksquashfs /theubuntuinstall ... /theplaceimsavingto [-noD -noI -noF]
```

Comment: Please use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered accounts and your registered accounts to be merged. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
sudo mksquashfs /path/to/original/install /path/to/baskup.sqfs
```

should work fine. You'll need to mount the original install and point `/path/to/original/install` to the mountpoint.

**Edit:** to use it without compression:

```
sudo mksquashfs /path/to/original/install /path/to/baskup.sqfs -noI -noD -noF -noX
```

All the `-no ...` options specify to remove compression for as much as possible.

Reference: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/mksquashfs

Comment: I really need no compression in the image.

Comment: @mango In that case, SquashFS is probably the wrong tool for the job. It's "a *highly compressed* read-only filesystem". You may want to look into [`tar`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tar.1.html).

Comment: I just meant that I need the noD noI and noF commands added to the commands you provided, and I'm not sure how to do it. I must use sqfs file format for this perticualar backup.